# Game Memory Issue

Tags: android, opengl-es

I published a 2d game on Google Play.I just catching runtime exeptions and i'm getting an exeption like this:

```
class java.lang.RuntimeException
Msg: com.androidgames.framework.gl.Texture.load:63 (OpenGL error code while loading texture: 1285 - bg/bg3.png)
```

I just look up this Error code and it means that GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY.Some devices sending this exeption and it's killing my game.My resources are only 13 MB but my game is crashing with this exeption even in Samsung Galaxy S2.What can cause to this problem?

Comment: You encountered the advanced version of the ever popular "bitmap size exceeds VM budget." error. Just 13MB of compressed (png, jpg) resources is like a GB of uncompressed data. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: @zapl Thank you.So how can i reduce the memory usage?When i look at a task manager it shows that my game is using 15 mb memory only.

Comment: 15mb ram should be okay but I don't know how exact task managers are (http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html is exact). Maybe you are using too much video memory (not sure how Android handles that) and need to unload textures that are not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15mb is a LOT on some phones.   You have to be really careful with memory.  You might try to use 2 bytes/pixels if you won't need all the colors of some images.

```
  options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
```

each pixel is stored in half the memory of full ARGB_8888 configuration.  My app was having similar issues and this helped tremendously

Comment: I'm using this like that but no change in quality,also tried ALPHA_8 to see whether quality will change but no change.

BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options);

Comment: then you've simply got to find a way to use less.  As I said, some devices have very limited memory. I was having the same problem on a Samsung Galaxy S phone - it has 336M of RAM but that shared among the OS and any other apps running.

Comment: Okey but how?Texture compression is a way to do that?

Comment: by removing from memory the textures you don't need and keeping in memory only the ones that are currently visible in the scene.  Culling is one way to do this, by using a bounding box of sorts that defines your view extents. Then you write code to determine if an object within that view requires a texture and then and only then loading the texture

Answer (score -1):

the error is in `bg/bg3.png` as you can see ..

try `decoding` your textures, and double check the resource `bg3.png`

Comment: What you mean with decode?Problem is not about with resources.In same device i'm getting another exeption with another resource.This happens in loading process.Problem is about RAM but my resources needed 15 mb ram only.